# How can Modulus function be used to prove that whether a given function is strict increasing or decreasing function?

Tags: functions

Ive been reading about functions lately and when i came upon reading *monotonic functions* then there was this prove given that a function $f(x)=3x-1$ is *strict increasing* and the function $f(x)=1-3x$ is *strict decreasing* as the *absolute value* of 
the function $f(x)=|x|$ is neither increasing or decreasing.

Please explain me this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what increasing and decreasing functions are?

A function is strictly increasing if, when you increase the argument, the value increases. For instance, $f(x)=3x-1$ is strictly increasing because if you increase $x$, $3x-1$ increases.

On the other hand, if $f(x)=1-3x$, and you increase $x$, then $1-3x$ decreases.

$|x|$ is slightly trickier, but think about $x=1$. If you increase to $x=2$, then $|x|$ increases from $1$ to $2$. However, if you take $x=-2$ and increase to $x=-1$, $|x|$ *decreases* from $2$ to $1$. Thus since it increases in some places and decreases in others, it's neither increasing nor decreasing.